# Understanding ConfigureAwait

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Trying to understand when I should use `ConfigureAwait()`.
According to book:

> When an `async` method resumes after an await, by default it will resume executing within the same context. This can cause performance problems if that context was a UI context and a large number of async methods are resuming on the UI context.

Solution

To avoid resuming on a context, await the result of `ConfigureAwait()` and pass false for its `continueOnCapturedContext` parameter:

```
async Task ResumeWithoutContextAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    //This method discards its context when it resumes.
}
```

What is context and how to see `ConfigureAwait()` changes things in sample application:

```
static async Task ResumeWithoutContextAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(true);
    Console.WriteLine("ManagedThreadId {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    //This method discards its context when it resumes.
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ResumeWithoutContextAsync();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I was thinking that context is `Thread`, but it is not.

Comment: There is a term called "blocking".  Some methods return when the work is completed synchronous (blocking) and others are asynchronous (non blocking) and return before all the work is completed.  await is needed when a method is non blocking and you need to wait until all work is completed.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 5):

Context here is `SynchronizationContext`. Await will post continuation (the rest of the method after await) to current context (`SynchronizationContext.Current`) if it's present and if you did not use `ConfigureAwait` false. If continuation is not posted to context - it will be executed on thread pool thread. In console applications there is no synhronization context by default, so in your test `ConfigureAwait` has no effect. You can create dummy context to see the effect though:

```
class MySynchornizationContext : SynchronizationContext {
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
        Console.WriteLine("posted");
        base.Post(d, state);
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
        Console.WriteLine("sent");
        base.Send(d, state);
    }
}
```

Then in the beginning of `Main` method:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new MySynchornizationContext());
```

With `ConfigureAwait(true)` (or without at all) - you will see that continuation was posted to context ("posted" line in console). With `ConfigureAwait(false)` - you will see it is not.

Real synchronization contexts are more complicated than that of course. For example UI context (like in winforms or WPF) will "queue" continuations and execute them on one (UI) thread. That might be problematic as described in your question quote, for various reasons (and may lead to deadlocks), so when you are writing general-purpose library - it's benefical to use `ConfigureAwait(false` to avoid this behavior.

`SynchronizationContext` is not required to post all callbacks to a single thread of course, it can do anything with them. For example ASP.NET MVC context (old versions at least) will post callbacks to the request thread, and there can be many requests so many request threads.

Answer (score -2):

Today we mostly write JSON services in fast services accessed via REST calls.  Native GUI applications and also IIS Application Server require async tasks resume execution on the original thread context. Unfortunately, that bias toward last century development forces us to use "ConfigureAwait(false)" on virtually every call in our service code.

Finally it's a really confusing and misleading name.  It reads as "do or do not configure await" but in fact it is "thread affinity true or false". There are no other options so it's NOT a general configuration method.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean "thread affinity true or false". The same synchronization context can be entered on different threads, as is the case with `AspNetSynchronizationContext`.